# How to solve "No such module 'ObjectMapper'" problem?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, objectmapper

I have a problem with my swift project on XCode. I use Cocoapods for the frameworks.
My project don't build. I have this error : `No such module 'ObjectMapper'`.

I have tried *pod install*, *pod update*, *pod deintegrate*, clean build folder, delete .xcworkspace file, delete derived data, update XCode, but nothing work.

The problem isn't the code because it had work well for this mac last week and today on other mac. It appeared after changing branches on my git.

Here is my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

def pods
    platform :ios, '13.2'
    pod 'RESideMenu'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'JSONHelper'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.18.0'
    pod 'KVNProgress'
    pod 'CalendarLib'
    pod 'Charts', '3.2.1'
    pod 'SwiftEventBus', :tag => '2.2.0', :git => 'https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus.git'
    pod 'RichEditorView', :git => 'https://github.com/T-Pro/RichEditorView.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'SwiftHSVColorPicker'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Toucan'
    pod 'RFQuiltLayout'
    pod 'Kingfisher'
    pod 'CropViewController', :tag => '2.4.0', :git => 'https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController.git'
    pod 'MatomoTracker', '~> 7'
    pod 'MaterialShowcase'
    pod 'UIDeviceIdentifier', :git => 'https://github.com/squarefrog/UIDeviceIdentifier.git'
end

post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              if ['RichEditorView', 'Toucan'].include? target.name
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
              else
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
              end
          end
      end
end


target 'targetName' do
    pods
end
```